# How to change the cell template in each row of mvc kendo grid

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, kendo-grid

I'm developing an application using Kendo UI for MVC and I want to be able to change the template of a cell but I don't know how to implement it using Kendo grid. I need to change the cell template in each row according to the value, if it is a 'string' I need to display text box, if date value then the cell template become date picker.Please help me to find a solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by using `EditorTemplates` (Views\Shared\EditorTemplates\ folder), which are partial views for types that you want. By default some editor templates are created, when you use `Telerik.ASP NET MVC Application` template for new project. 
Also you can specify required View via `UIHint("ViewName")` attribute.

Comment: Thank you Andrey.I have to add different templates in a same cell When I bound column with string property column becomes string. I have 3 different templates for same column 'EmployeeTemplate'. The value of 'EmployeeTemplate' is determined  by 'EmployeeType' column and I need to display datepicker, int or string templates in a cell.

when i add,

public string MetadataColumnValue {get;set;}

columns.Bound(c => c.MetadataColumnValue).ClientTemplate("#= MetadataDateTime #").Width("20%");

data grid column  columns.Bound(c => c.MetadataColumnValue) becomes string. date picker did not display.

Comment: Do you need to display DatePicker in display or editor template?